How to position the browser validation message when using a Select2 component
I'm trying to replace a standard <select> with a Select2 in an existing form.
The form logic was written in Vanilla JS, with the client-side validation left to the browser.
The problem is the placement of the error message generated by the browser when I use a Select2 component:


document.querySelectorAll("[data-is=select2]").forEach(el => {
  // the Select2 component only works with JQuery objects
  let $jqo = $(el);
  $jqo.select2({
    width: "auto",
    placeholder: el.firstElementChild.textContent
  });
  // making sure select2 works with the existing handlers
  $jqo.on("select2:select", ev => el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")));
});
form {
  width: 20rem;
}
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1ch;
}
/* making select and Select2 occupy the remaining space */
select, .select2-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Standard select example --!>
<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      Greetings:
      <select name="greetings" required>
        <option hidden disabled value="" selected>Select a Greetings</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Standard select">
</form>

<hr>

<!-- Standard select replaced with a Select2 component !-->
<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      Greetings:
      <select data-is="select2" name="greetings" required>
        <option hidden disabled value="" selected>Select2 a Greetings</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Select2 select">
</form>



As you can see after clicking on the buttons, the validation message of Select2 gets placed under the <label> instead of the <select>.
How can I fix it? Preferably without JQuery.

Why not just disable the button until an item in the parent select is selected and validation is complete?

That could be a workaround indeed, but not ideal because it's best to point out where the error is.

I found out that Select2 applies a position: absolute to the select, which explains why the error message is displayed under "Greetings". I should be able to fix the problem by putting the <select data-is="select2"> inside a `. That won't be not a "progressive enhancement" anymore though...

Apply label { display: inline-grid; }, and slightly position <select>:


document.querySelectorAll("[data-is=select2]").forEach(el => {
  // the Select2 component only works with JQuery objects
  let $jqo = $(el);
  $jqo.select2({
    width: "auto",
    placeholder: el.firstElementChild.textContent
  });
  // making sure select2 works with the existing handlers
  $jqo.on("select2:select", ev => el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")));
});
form {
  width: 20rem;
}
label {
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1ch;
  
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  .select2-hidden-accessible {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    left: 8px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Standard select example --!>
<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      Greetings:
      <select name="greetings" required>
        <option hidden disabled value="" selected>Select a Greetings</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Standard select">
</form>

<hr>

<!-- Standard select replaced with a Select2 component !-->
<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      Greetings:
      <select data-is="select2" name="greetings" required>
        <option hidden disabled value="" selected>Select2 a Greetings</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Select2 select">
</form>




very nice, and doesn't need any markup editing

but I can't get the select and select2 boxes to occupy the remaining width of the form

I've edited your answer to make std select and Select2 span the remaining width of the line; Also, I used the .select2-hidden-accessible class to target the hidden select of Select2 specifically
